# A ghost deleted my files?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a pretty weird situation here, and i came up with a very strange conclusion, the thing that makes me think that i got it all wrong, that i have cured the scratch with hcl or something !

Anyways, two days ago i found out that all the pages in a certain directory on a web app that I work on stopped working;

When I tried to debug, iis shout out an exception at my face, the exception was kinda weird (and very ambiguous to me), it says

> "type Global is declared in an
>   assembly that is not referenced here"

and the cursor pointed to a line of code in the generated asp.net temp files, so i checked up my bin directory and compared the live version (the broken version) to my own local version (the working version) and found a couple of dlls missing on the live version

i copied those dlls from the local to the live, and everything went just fine!

the question is, where did files go in the first place, and if the temporary asp.net files were corrupted, is there is any way to fix them without having to reinstall the framework, or rebuild the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Temporary ASP.Net files are created whenever your web asp.net app has to compile. (If you search this site or Google, you will find many descriptions and information on how this works.) They can be safely deleted at any time, so long as the original files are available to recompile. No reinstallation of .NET framework needed.

I doubt that anyone is going to be able to tell you where they went. Your best bet is to put some auditing on the files and log the deletes to the event log.

Its possible that ...

- someone else who has access to the server deleted the files accidentally or on purpose.
- you deleted them accidentally
- you were hacked
- your files were deemed viral and were quarantined by an anti virus.

Probably a few other reasons I cant think of too...